# PROC GEOCODE: SAS University?

Tags: sas, geocode

I am having issues invoking PROC GEOCODE. I have SAS University and when I type the function it appears to highlighted blue just like other functions, however, when I run the code it gives me this error:

**ERROR: Procedure GEOCODE not found**

Is Geocode included in SAS University, if not, is there a way to download it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just as a suggestion that Google provides free functionality of geocoding that you can tap into by using PROC HTTP in SAS University.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge `PROC GEOCODE` is a SAS/GRAPH procedure which is not included in the SAS University default depot list. You can try to rerun the SAS installer, choose 'add SAS depot' and check the SAS/GRAPH box if any.

Comment: There's no installer/depot for SAS UE, it comes installed on a locked down VM.